# How to use findViewById in onCreate() method in Service class?

Tags: java, android

When I used `onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle   savedInstanceState)`, the problem is that `oncreateview` can't exist in `Service` class.

```
public class FloatingViewService extends Service{
    CircleMenu circleMenu;
    public FloatingViewService() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    //Inflate the floating view layout we created
    mFloatingView = LayoutInflater
       .from(this)
       .inflate(R.layout.layout_floating_widget, null);
    circleMenu = (CircleMenu) findViewById(R.id.circle_menu);
}
```

Comment: it's not a common practice handling view events on a service. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i want to do circlemenu with floating view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the last line to:

```
circleMenu = (CircleMenu) mFloatingView.findViewById(R.id.circle_menu);
```

Comment: Ooh that's Right ,Thank you very much